# "Type a tag" text cut off

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, design

I've noticed that the background text "Type a tag" at the bottom of the "Ask Question" page is cut off:

> [image: "Typ" instead of "Type a tag"]

Reproduced in Microsoft Edge.

Comment: Also reproduced on Firefox and Chrome latest on Mac.

Comment: `style="width: 19px;"`. A dev must have been drunken coding.

Comment: Cross-site dupe on Meta.SO: [Tags input placeholder text cut off](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/374060/4642212).

Comment: @Xufox this is a Stack Exchange wide issue, and this is the proper place for it to be addressed.

Comment: @Malachi I just linked to the issue as reported on Meta.SO. I didn’t stop anyone from addressing it here.

Comment: @Malachi It's perfectly normal to link to the same bug report on another per-site meta, so that when employees tag this question as completed, they also tag the other one.

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog much better is to allow closing the question as cross-site duplicate. To prevent duplication on any level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed on Friday Sept. 14 - code intended for the internal Teams editor snuck into the public sites without associated styles (or consideration of what guidance is needed for tagging on public sites). Jisoo corrected this by limiting this behavior to Teams.