# Remove “at least one tag is required” near the tag field

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, design

I see no reason to show “at least one tag is required” near the tag field because almost same text will be appeared if you’ll try post a question without a tag:

> [image]

Also it’s not truly request due to restrictions of meta sites, where you must use at least one **specific** tag:

> [image]

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/315383/type-a-tag-text-cut-off

Comment: I don't know about this. The red text is an error message. You have to click the submit button before you even see that message. Wouldn't it be best to let the user know beforehand that at least one tag is required? Thus saving the user an extra click.

Comment: A compromise would be to remove that message and change the placeholder text to say something like "type at least one tag"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed on Friday Sept. 14 - code intended for the internal Teams editor snuck into the public sites without associated styles (or consideration of what guidance is needed for tagging on public sites). Jisoo corrected this by limiting this behavior to Teams.

[image: placeholder text (within tag field): "must include at least one of (bug feature-request discussion support)"]

Comment: Is it possible to add commas between tags in the placeholder?

Comment: Is it *possible*? Sure. Why would that be an improvement?

Comment: since items in list should be separated by commas in English, isn’t it?

Comment: it's possible, but not needed. FWIW, you can separate tags with commas in the editor too, but they just get stripped.

Comment: editor displays tags like labels, not just raw text. But placeholder is pure text, I think such sentences should use grammatically correct typography.

Comment: Moreover I suggested to [use square brackets around tag names](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/289866/339911) in raw string.

Comment: The editor *displays* tags with special formatting, but they're input / edited as text, @alexolut. Try it: you can type (or paste) `feature-request tags design` or `feature-request,tags,design` or even `[feature-request] [tags] [design]` into the editor and it'll be accepted (and normalized to a space-separated list). If you think it'd be easier for folks to understand a comma-separated list, post a feature-request - you might be right.